# Where I can find "Domain Service Class" and "Authentication Domain Service"?

Tags: silverlight

Trying to do some coding on silverlight, seems pretty hard without right instructions, maybe it is because itself changed pretty quick?

I see posts about using Domain Service Class, and Authentication Domain Service, but no several machines with new installed VS 2015 with silverlight SDK, On none of them I can find the two templates.

I read somewhere says Domain Service Class is already included in SL 5, but what about Authentication Domain Service?

Comment: On the `.Web` project run `install-package RIAServices.Server` and on the client, you need at least `RIAServices.Silverlight`. Alternatively you can install the RiaServices toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.
On SL 5, Domain service changes to RIA service, but the Domain service lib dlls are already included in the web project